# Python: using rolling + apply with a function that requires 2 columns as arguments in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, function, multiple-columns, apply

I have a dataframe (df) with 2 columns:

```
Out[2]: 
    0   1
0   1   2
1   4   5
2   3   6
3  10  12
4   1   2
5   4   5
6   3   6
7  10  12
```

I would like to use calculate for all the elements of df[0] a function of itself and df[1] column:

```
def custom_fct_2(x,y):
    res=stats.percentileofscore(y.values,x.iloc[-1])
    return res
```

I get the following error:  TypeError:

```
("'numpy.float64' object is not callable", u'occurred at index 0')
```

Here is the full code:

```
from __future__ import division
import pandas as pd
import sys
from scipy import stats

def custom_fct_2(x,y):
    res=stats.percentileofscore(y.values,x.iloc[-1])
    return res

df= pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[4,5],[3,6],[10,12],[1,2],[4,5],[3,6],[10,12]])
df['perc']=df.rolling(3).apply(custom_fct_2(df[0],df[1]))
```

Can someone help me on that? ( I am new in Python)

```
Out[2]: 

        0   1
...
    5   4   5
    6   3   6
    7  10  12

I want the percentile ranking of [10] in [12,6,5]
I want the percentile ranking of [3] in [6,5,2]
I want the percentile ranking of [4] in [5,2,12]
...
```

Comment: Why apply, just calling func should be fine ``custom_fct_2(df[0], df[1])``

Comment: Hi,
because the next step is to do it "Rolling":
b = df.rolling(3).apply(custom_fct_2(df[0],df[1]))

It is like a rolling percentile.

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: a vector [8,1] ( serie or list)  

for each x in columns df[0] I want the percentile of x in the last 3 data in df[1].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that `rolling().apply()` function cannot give you a segment of 3 rows across all the columns. Instead, it gives you series for the column 0 first, then the column 1.

Maybe there are better solutions, but I would show my one which at least works.

```
df= pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[4,5],[3,6],[10,12],[1,2],[4,5],[3,6],[10,12]])

def custom_fct_2(s):
  score = df[0][s.index.values[1]]  # you may use .values[-1] if you want the last element
  a = s.values
  return stats.percentileofscore(a, score)
```

I'm using the same data you provided. But I modified your `custom_fct_2()` function. Here we get the `s` which is a series of 3 rolling values from the column 1. Fortunately, we have indexes in this series, so we can get the score from the column 0 via the "middle" index of the series. BTW, in Python `[-1]` means the last element of a collection, but from your explanation, I believe you actually want the middle one.

Then, apply the function.

```
# remove the shift() function if you want the value align to the last value of the rolling scores
df['prec'] = df[1].rolling(3).apply(custom_fct_2).shift(periods=-1)
```

The `shift` function is optional. It depends on your requirements whether your `prec` need to be aligned with column 0 (the middle score is using) or the rolling scores of column 1. I would assume you need it.